# php parse_str crashes on big data

Tags: php, xml

I try to post very long (10-15MB) `xml` data. Therefore I have increased in my development `php.ini` the following settings:

```
max_execution_time = 600
max_input_time = -1
memory_limit = 1024M
post_max_size = 5000M
upload_max_filesize = 5000M
default_socket_timeout = 600
```

But the `php` function `parse_str` still seems to crash - since all following commands are not executed and the page-response is 0 bytes.

I am not really a php guru, could anywone give me a hint how to fix this issue?

EDIT:
There is no log, no response and apache error log is also not complaining anything

why I use parse_str? this is not my code :-)

EDIT2:
We use a CMS tool, and we have some plugins - sending xml via querystring is a workaround to a limitation. Usually the XML got parsed and inserted into a custom databse (not CMS Database). I have just inserted some file prints to check what is going on:

```
public function upsertItem($oXMLObjectFromExtern="")
{

    $bHasError = false;
    $iInserted = 0;
    $iUpdated = 0;
    $iErrors = 0;
    $output = "";

    $sPostData = file_get_contents("php://input");
    // works
    $fh = fopen('/var/log/apache2/kic.log', 'w');
    fwrite($fh, $sPostData);

    parse_str($sPostData, $aPostData);

    // does not do anything, no error messages nothing ... 
    $fh = fopen('/var/log/apache2/kic2.log', 'w');
    //fwrite($fh, "jetzt");
    fwrite($fh, var_export($aPostData,TRUE));

    if(!empty($aPostData['data']) OR is_object($oXMLObjectFromExtern)){
```

The query string is formated like so: op=upsertitem&data=%3Crows%3E%0A%3Crow%3E%0A%3Cft_short_name%.... more encoded xml data

Comment: Why are you using parse_str() on such a large string? When was the last time you used a 10MB+ query string? And why are you using it with XML data?

Comment: `parse_str` doesn't seem to take XML data, anything else going on?

Comment: So you're not responsible for writing the code; but you should at least be able to give a clue on what it's doing with smaller volumes of XML data - it's not the type of thing most of us are likely ever to have done in the past

Comment: smaler volumes are no problem at all, up to 5000 records are accepted and inserted in my database very well

Comment: are you sure the script operated on xml data in the past? take a look at the php.net docu (it's really quite good) - parse_str expects a string that is formatted like a query string (foo=bar&baz=gnu..). Also, try error_reporting = -1 in your ini

Comment: yes the string is formated like so: op=upsertitem&data=%3Crows%3E%0A%3Crow%3E%0A%3Cft_short_name%.... more encoded xml data ...

Comment: Why are you doing `parse_str` on `"php://input"`?  Wouldn't that just be `$_POST` (or `$_GET`)?

Comment: $_POST is just empty too ...

Comment: Is there anything in your `/var/log/apache2/kic.log` file?

Comment: yes the kic.log contains all the posted data (complete query string), but the kic2 file does not exist afterwards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was curious and found this:

[post on the php-internal mailing list](http://grokbase.com/t/php/php-internals/123epc6d2m/let-parse-str-parse-more-than-max-input-vars-args)

apparently str_parse takes the `max_input_vars` ini setting as a limiter...so that would be another setting you have to tweak.

I still don't fully understand why that skript fails silently, though...did you try to set the error_reporting level to show everything ( if the ini setting doesn't work, try `error_reporting(E_ALL)` in the script)?

Did you monitor your serverprocess to see if the execution either reaches your memory limit or maxes out the CPU?

p.s. I still think using parse_str here is a bit of a hack ;)

Comment: Thanks! putting error_reporting(E_ALL) at the beginning of the function helped, now I start getting errors: "Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 31503193 bytes)in /var/www/module/ftfunctions/static/ftapi/putxml.php on line 484", Line 484 is the write to the kic2 file.

Comment: You are my hero, thank you! And for some reason, some php.ini settings are without any effect i.e. error_reporting = E_ALL and so is memory_limit. I also had to add these two lines `ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M'); error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the beginning of my function and everytrhing is fine now! Thank you very much!